# SSIS moving Dirty/Failed Rows to File or Table

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS package that gets data from a SQL SERVER 2008 TABLE (table A)on one server to a SQL SERVER 2008 table(table B) on another server and then convert the data and move it to another table.

I'm using a data flow task to do the above.
 The datatype of 2 columns, column 1 and column 2 in both the tables is varchar(60) and varchar(50) respectively.

I need to import the data from table B which is the staging table to a final table(table C).The data type of the above 2 columns is of type int in table C. I'm converting the above  2 columns to int data type when I import the data, for which I have a dataflow task, in which the OLEDB source
 has the following query:

SELECT CAST(COLUMN1 AS INT), COLUMN2 AS INT)
 FROM TABLE B

Hi

I have 2 SQL tables i.e OLEDB Data sources , one which has the correct rows(that have been successfully converted to int) thru green arrow, and the other that has erroneous rows(that throw an error) thru  red arrow.(It is configured to redirect row only on conversion error, it has "failed component" option  when a truncation error occurs)the oledb destination tables has the same structure as Source Table.

When I run the  data flow task that imports data from Source Table to Destination Table, I get an error
 "invalid character value for cast specification" or the data conversion error.
 I do not want it throw an error, but rather redirect the erroneous rows to the error table with the same structure as the destination table, with same structure has source table with error no and column name

Would it be a good idea to use a data conversion task and redirect the errors rows, by configuring an error output on conversion as well as truncation or just on conversion or cast the value  and redirect rows only when conversion error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

As the CAST error occurs within the SQL engine you cannot redirect those rows using SSIS.  I would use a data conversion task and redirect the error rows.

FWIW I'm not a fan of "error tables" - in my experience no-one every looks at them.  I prefer the "aggressive load" style (even the name is cool) where you force all rows in and make the analysts explain the discrepancies. They soon get around to fixing the serious issues as they distort their results.  There will always be a low level of trivial errors that its best not to get hung up on, with life being so short and all...

Comment: Hi Mike, We are doing loading of File data into Table, we can provide analyst to correct, correction of large file is little bit complex. I make have file with 1,00,000 rows, where the chances of having error rows in files are less say 50-100. If want copy these dirty rows into table or file and provide tht file to user to correct and do data movement.

Comment: Sounds good in theory.  In practice the error files are gradually ignored (after some initial enthusiasm) and your data completeness steadily degrades. When decision makers realise this, they lose confidence in your whole app and your whole project becomes pointless.